# Extracting data points (statistics) from matplotlib and equations

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I have the following code that runs to a graph, what I want is to extract the X,Y and Z into a list (so I can copy them later in excel, and play with the numbers), basically the other way around of having a set of data and plotting it into a graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
from matplotlib import cm  
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter  

import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
N = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
M = np.arange(0, 15, 1)
N, M = np.meshgrid(N, M)
DNM = 3992.88*N - 2585.96*M

surf = ax.plot_surface(N, M, DNM, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-25000, 20000)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to convert your 2d array `dnm` to a x-y-z format:

```py
n, m = dnm.shape
rows, cols = np.mgrid[:n,:m]
xyz = np.column_stack((rows.ravel(), cols.ravel(), dnm.ravel()))
```

Then you can write the resulting array `xyz` into an excel file using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(xyz)
xyz_path = "xyz.xlsx"
df.to_excel(xyz_path, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the x, y and z that you used to plot the figure. They are named `N, M, DNM` in your code. But these are 2D arrays, so all you have to do is convert them into 1D arrays for easy plot and manipulation inside Excel.

```
x, y, z = N.ravel(), M.ravel(), DNM.ravel()
```

Now, if you want to limit the z-range, apply logical indexing `-25000 ≤ z ≤ 20000` like this:

```
limits = np.logical_and(z >= -25000, z <= 20000)
x, y, z = x[limits], y[limits], z[limits]
```

Finally, you can save as text using `np.savetxt` or save to an Excel file as @blunova did:

```
import pandas as pd

xyz = np.column_stack((x, y, z))
df = pd.DataFrame(xyz)
xyz_path = "xyz.xlsx"
df.to_excel(xyz_path, index=False)
```

Comment: Hi, I just realized you commented her as I was asking again on something went wrong, thank you first and foremost.  the code I used from ur help is as following: x, y, z = N.ravel(), M.ravel(), DNM.ravel()
#
limits = np.logical_and(z >= -25000, z <= 20000)
x, y, z = x[limits], y[limits], z[limits]
#
xyz = np.column_stack((x, y, z))
df = pd.DataFrame(xyz)
xyz_path = "xyz.csv"
df.to_csv(xyz_path, index=False).